# Textures turned into checkerboard [solved]

Tags: texturing

I was using plane track feature in blender and after reloading, 90% of all textures that I extracted that way turned into checkerboard. And that happened everytime I tried duplicating an object with a texture from plane track. Also the thumbnails of the textures are saved and normal, but the main texture is just checker board. I am very annoyed by this, I couldn't find any solutions to this problem on internet :/
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you more precisely describe the steps you followed? How did you extract the textures?

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I opened movie clip editor/tracking/clip and loaded an image to extract textures from it, then I created 4 track points and in the Solve tab I pressed Create Plane Track while selecting 4 point. It created a adjustable plane that I adjusted to the wall in the image and the on the right side of the screen In the Track tab in Plane Track I opened a dropdown where I clicked New Image From Plane Tracker.
For more context I followed this tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyr3BUKRl0E&t=5s&ab_channel=CGMatter) 'link'

Comment: Did you save the texture before realoding anything? It's not mentioned in the tutorial (may be Tom figured that the audience would already know that) but in blender, you need to save the image physically or pack it or it will be lost eventually (and randomly).

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Yes, I think it may be it. I forgot to save them. Thank you!

Comment: To make sure you don't lose them, save them physicaly on your drive with `Image`>`Save as` or  `Image`>`Save as Copy`. Sometimes packed images get corrupted too.